# Why this application of the chain rule yields a transpose function?.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I took this problem from Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds (2-13b).

> If $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ are differentiable and $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined by $h(t)=\langle f(t),g(t)\rangle$ show that $h'(a)=\langle f'(a)^T,g(a)\rangle+\langle f(a),g'(a)^T\rangle.$

My issue here is the transpose that is supposed to be in the solution, because it seems to me that here the inner product is well defined considering $<f'(a),g(a)>$ and the other inner product as well.

In the former part (2-13a) I proved that if $IP:\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined by $IP(x,y)=\langle x,y\rangle$ then $(IP)'(a,b)=(b,a)$. I used this with the chain rule to compute $h'$ but I didn't get exactly I was supposed to.

Here $h=(IP)\circ(f,g))$ then $$dh_{a}=d(IP\circ(f,g))_{a}=dIP(f,g)_{a}\cdot d(f,g)_a\\=dIP(f,g)_a\cdot (df_a,dg_a)=(g(a),f(a))\cdot (f'(a),g'(a))\\=f'(a)g(a)+g(a)f'(a) = \langle f'(a),g(a)\rangle+\langle g(a),f'(a)\rangle.$$

Where is the problem with what I did?

Comment: What is $a$ for this problem?  It seems to already be defined in the question statement.

Comment: $a$ is a random real number, the point where $h'$ is evaluated.

Comment: Then should the problem read, "show that $h'(a) = \ldots$" instead of "show that $h'(t) = \ldots$"?

Comment: Yes! :), that was my typo, it should read as you said.

Comment: In your question, should it be $g'(a)^T$ instead of $g(a)^T$?

Comment: In this case, just realize that $f$ and $f'$ are in 2 *different* spaces.  1 is in the space of row vectors, the other in the space of column vectors.  So when you wrote $\langle f'(a), g(a) \rangle$, you were taking the inner product of two different types of objects (you'll learn later that that's normally how its done, but if that's not the definition Spivak gave you, then it's undefined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take that $i(x,y)=\langle x,y\rangle$ is the canonical inner product in Euclidean space. Then your formula is not correct. The derivative of the inner product at point $(a,b)$ is the linear transformation that sends $(x,y)$ to $\langle x,b\rangle +\langle a,y\rangle$, since $$\langle a+h,b+k\rangle -\langle a,b\rangle=\langle h,b\rangle+\langle a,k\rangle+\langle h,k\rangle$$

and $\langle h,k\rangle \leqslant \frac 1 2 \lVert h,k\rVert^2$. Maybe you can try again now? Use the chain rule.